# How to handle precision when dealing with currency in MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, rounding, currency-formatting

I have three fields in an invoice table:

```
subtotal    decimal(12,4)
tax_amount  decimal(12,4)
total       decimal(12,4)
```

I have run into a problem with rounding. So there's an invoice with the following values. The addition adds up, but when displaying the invoice data and generating a pdf for the invoice, the displayed data doesn't always add up.

```
           stored value     displayed (rounded)
                                value
subtotal    165.1610         165.16 
tax_amount  24.7742          24.77
total       189.9352         189.94
```

The stored values add up. The `total` column is calculated by adding the `subtotal` and `tax_amount` values in PHP. The rounding was done correctly but 165.16 + 24.77 = **189.93** and NOT 189.94.

How can I handle these situations? This is not always the case.

Comment: welcome to the joys of floating point numbers. you cannot fix the problem directly. bypass it. store your cash values as pennies instead of fractional dollars.  `(16516 + 2477) / 100` will work out better in the end.

Comment: @MarcB Do you really think this is a floating number problem? It will even happen with integer values. The problem is to store all 3 three values. He should calculate the total by adding subtotal to tax_amount. The database is not normalized because total is functional dependend of subtotal and tax_amount. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency

Comment: @steven I didn't normalize the table because I wanted to avoid having to add the values everytime I need them to be displayed. This would allow for someone to add the values with 4 decimal points and then round the result in one place, but another developer could round before adding, giving different results. This table is a record of a printed out invoice so it has to store the real value that was given to the customer everytime.

Comment: yes, but why you need to store it with 4 decimal points? Avoid the rounding problem by storing 2 decimal points and build total as rounded sum of subtotal and tax_amount (round before sum). Listen to @DavidWyly and avoid fractional pennies whenever possible.

Comment: I'm storing 4 decimal points because I read [this article](https://rietta.com/blog/2012/03/03/best-data-types-for-currencymoney-in/) which mentioned that that's the way to be compliant with the [Generally Accepted Accounting Principles](http://www.fasab.gov/authoritative-source-of-gaap/). Now I'm thinking that it's too complicated. I come from a Magento background and I remember this is how they stored currency amounts so I just decided to go that way.

Comment: however, the stored 4 decimal total value is not the value you will get payed. so at least this value should be 2 decimal. Because you cannot receive fractional pennies. And so sums of the total field will never be correct by using 4 digits. Even no roundig of that values will help.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Well I'll get to changing my table definitions then. It will be way simpler. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Round the stored values to the nearest penny. When you're calculating a total or subtotal using PHP, sum up the *rounded* values.

If you're going to be displaying rounded aggregates a certain way, it's probably best practice to calculate it the exact same way to avoid confusion.

You **could** display the aggregate items as not being rounded, and then round the final sum for display purposes. This may play more nicely in the long run if you're storing fractional pennies in the database.

Another option could be having a rounding charge on the invoice to account for the discrepancy, though that may confuse some people.

That being said, programmatically speaking, it's best to avoid fractional pennies whenever possible.

> *Whatever you choose to do, be consistent!*

Comment: I'm storing 4 decimal points because I read [this article](https://rietta.com/blog/2012/03/03/best-data-types-for-currencymoney-in/) which mentioned that that's the way to be compliant with the [Generally Accepted Accounting Principles](http://www.fasab.gov/authoritative-source-of-gaap/). I'm having my doubts though.

Comment: The reason for 4 decimal points is because any rounding errors tend to even out over thousands of transactions. It doesn't mean you're completely immune to an invoice being off by $0.01 or so; you're still going to have to try to account for those discrepancies when they happen in a consistent manner.